# Flask SQLAlchemy : How do I get 5 recent rows?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class here that stores a post's content, author, and time posted.

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


class Post(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    contents = db.Column(db.String(700))
    author = db.Column(db.String(100))
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    
    def __init__(self, title, contents, author):
        self.title = title
        self.contents = contents
        self.author = author
        self.time = datetime.now()
```

My question is how do I get the 5 most recent posts? I am using Flask with SQL Alchemy for this. I tried

```
print(db.session.query(Post).order_by(Post.time.desc()).limit(5).all())
....
post= Post(title, content, Users.query.filter_by(email=session['email']).first())
db.session.add(post)
db.session.commit()
```

but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error of your code is actually not from the database as you would see. It is really from the fact that your are passing a user object as a string in the 'author' column. Just use something else for the author column like their name or an identifying id if you have that. Try:

```
post= Post(title, content, Users.query.filter_by(email=session['email']).first().id)
db.session.add(post)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Worked great with my database now. Do you know how I can query the User object as a whole into a column. I don't have anything set up for reading in id's.

Answer (score 1):

Use `order_by` parameter .

For Example :  `db.session.query(Post).order_by(Post.id.desc()).limit(5).all()`

Comment: I usually use Post.query.filter_by(param=param). Is there a way to make your line of code into that kind of format? I tried this: Post.query.order_by(time).limit(5).all() but that doesn't work because it is a a datetime date.today() element. How do I get around that?

Comment: I think it is an problem with data type you used . Change `String` field to `Date` filed.

Comment: How do I change it to a date? I did time = db.Column(date) and got sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: 'SchemaItem' object, such as a 'Column' or a 'Constraint' expected, got <class 'datetime.date'>

Comment: `time = db.Column(db.DateTime) `

Comment: Hm it is still not working. What are your imports? I only imported from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

Comment: I've included some of my imports in the code

Comment: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/ Refer this

Comment: I used the db.datetime in the column but I still get this sort of error: sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO post (title, contents, author, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('a', 'a', <Users 1>, '2020-12-22 08:03:36.828497')] nothing seems to hold up

Comment: Change data type in your database.